# How can I partially transpose a table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like this:

| id | source | score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 10 |
| 1 | b | 15 |
| 2 | a | 20 |
| 2 | c | 25 |

In this table, `id` and `source` make up a unique key. `source` can be one of 'a', 'b' or 'c'.

I want to transform it into this:

| id | score_a | score_b | score_c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 15 | 0 |
| 2 | 20 | 0 | 25 |

I don't mind if the 0s are nulls instead, if that would make it easier.

The target table should be the result of the following steps:

```
for every row in the table:
    if source = 'a', add or update a row with id and score_a = score
    if source = 'b', add or update a row with id and score_b = score
    if source = 'c', add or update a row with id and score_c = score
```

I tried the following statement:

```
select id, score as score_a, null as score_b, null as score_c from tbl where source = 'a'
union all
select id, null as score_a, score as score_b, null as score_c from tbl where source = 'b'
union all
select id, null as score_a, null as score_b, score as score_c from tbl where source = 'c'
```

But it gave me this result instead:

| id | score_a | score_b | score_c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | null | null |
| 2 | 20 | null | null |
| 1 | null | 15 | null |
| 2 | null | null | 25 |

How can I get a table like the one I want (with distinct id)?

Comment: Is the combination of `id` and `score` unique?

Comment: @PM77-1 yes, it's unique. It could even be a primary key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to use `CASE` to implement your logic and then flatten the result with some aggregation (I used `MAX()`)

```sql
SELECT id,
       MAX(CASE WHEN source='a' THEN score END) as score_a,
       MAX(CASE WHEN source='b' THEN score END) as score_b,
       MAX(CASE WHEN source='c' THEN score END) as score_c
FROM Tbl
GROUP BY id
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/f1724a/2)

You indicated that `null` was OK, but if you have to have zeroes instead add `COALESCE()`

Comment: Yes, conditional aggregation is a way to pivot data in SQL. An alternative syntax would be to use the filter clause: `MAX(score) FILTER (WHERE source = 'a') AS score_a`. And the OP may want to add an `ORDER BY id`, too.